# Arrange elements in an array in a specific order

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

Found this interview question on Careercup

Given an array A with n integers. 
Rearrange array such that 
A[0]<=A[1]>=A[2]<=A[3]>=A[4]<=A[5] and so on

Edit: Array is not sorted and You have to do it in linear time O(N)

I am unable to find a solution in linear time, the closest I get is sort the array and then rearrange elements. Anyone has idea how it can be done in linear time? Can this be even done in linear time?

My proposed solution is to sort the array in nlogn time and then rearrange every odd element i with i-1 and i+1 alternatively.

Comment: Please add the solution you came up with.

Comment: You don't have to sort it.  Those inequalities can't be associative.  You only need to satisfy them for nearest neighbours.

Comment: @StarsAreBack: Please check my updated answer

Comment: @appzYourLife Sorry For the delay. I have made a comment. Please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this function (the code is in Swift) to arrange the array in a *Wave Form* in time **O(n)**.

```
func wave(inout list: [Int]) {
    let evenIndexes = (0..<list.count).filter { $0 % 2 == 0 }

    for index in evenIndexes {
        if index > 0 && list[index] > list[index-1] {
            swap(&list[index], &list[index-1])
        }

        if index < list.count - 1 && list[index] > list[index+1] {
            swap(&list[index], &list[index+1])
        }
    }
}
```

This solution is based on the algorithm described [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sort-array-wave-form-2/).

### Test

```
var test0 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
wave(&test0)
print(test0) // [1, 3, 2, 5, 4, 6]

var test1 = [4, 6, 2, 1, 3, 7]
wave(&test1)
print(test1) // [4, 6, 1, 3, 2, 7]

var test2 = [20, 9, 4, 2, 0]
wave(&test2)
print(test2) // [9, 20, 2, 4, 0]
```

### Time complexity

The function has a `for loop` executed n/2 times (only for the even indexes). So the for loop has time complexity `O(n)`.

Inside the `for loop` we found a couple of `if then` statement, both are executed in constante time so `O(1)`.

So the time complexity is `O(n) * O(1) = O(n)` where n is the number of elements in the input array.

Comment: Can you check the output for the unsorted array? I think it wont work for unsorted array. Example: 4, 6, 2, 1, 3, 7

Comment: With you input `[4, 6, 2, 1, 3, 7]` the output is `[6, 2, 4, 1, 7, 3]`.

Comment: But here 6 cannot be at first place as it is larger than 2, the second element

Comment: @StarksAreBack: updated, now it should be correct. I just changed `<` to this `>` in both the `IF` statements. Let me know if you want me to try other inputs.

Comment: In the last output case 9, 20, 2, 4, 0   0 is lesser than 4, should be greater than 4.

Comment: no it fails for the last case, as 0 is smaller than 4

Comment: @StarksAreBack: wait, what should be the output for this input `20, 9, 4, 2, 0`?

Comment: I think the problem is because the length of the input array is odd. In this case you cannot have the last number greater then the previous one.

Answer (score 3):

Use [quickselect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect) to find the median of the array in O(n). This will allow you to divide the array in two equal (or almost equal) parts: those who are less than or equal to the median (A) up to n/2 elements, and the rest (B), that will be, by definition, greater than or equal to the median.

Arrange the array using this two halves like the following:

```
A B A B A B A
```

This will be correct, because every item `A` will be less than or equal to every `B`, by definition.

Comment: Can you please describe this in more detail? I am lost after using quickselect first time, do we repeat it for all elements here?

Comment: @JuanLopez: are you sure the `QuickSelect` can always be done in `O(n)`? Wikipedia does say that in the worst case it is `O(n^2)`

Comment: @appzYourLife QuickSelect with median-of-medians is always O(n): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians

Comment: https://github.com/anish198519851985/Hacking/blob/master/arrange_specific_order.py works as described.

Answer (score 0):

C# implementation of O(n) solution with usage of NthElement algorithm:

```cs
public void WaveSortTest(int[] a)
{
    var nthElement = NthElement(a, a.Length / 2);
    var element = a[nthElement];

    var odd = 1;
    var even = 0;
    var r = new int[a.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] <= element)
        {
            r[even] = a[i];
            even += 2;
        }
        else
        {
            r[odd] = a[i];
            odd += 2;
        }
    }

    PrintArray(r);
}

private static readonly Random _rnd = new Random((int)DateTime.Today.ToFileTimeUtc());

private static int NthElement(int[] arr, int k)
{
    return NthElement(arr, 0, arr.Length, k);
}

private static int NthElement(int[] arr, int low, int high, int k)
{
    var pos = low + _rnd.Next(high - low);
    Swap(arr, pos, high - 1);

    var i = Partition(arr, low, high);

    if (k < i)
    {
        return NthElement(arr, low, i, k);
    }
    if (k > i)
    {
        return NthElement(arr, i + 1, high, k);
    }
    return i;
}

private static int Partition(int[] arr, int low, int high)
{
    var i = low - 1;
    for (var j = low; j < high; j++)
    {
        if (arr[j] <= arr[high - 1])
        {
            i++;
            Swap(arr, i, j);
        }
    }
    return i;
}

private static void Swap<T>(T[] a, int first, int second)
{
    var t = a[first];
    a[first] = a[second];
    a[second] = t;
}

private static void PrintArray(IEnumerable<int> arr)
{
    foreach (var item in arr)
    {
        Console.Write(item + " ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```